# condensing AS3 Timers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

Ok so I have a grid of movie clips, a total of 25, and I am trying to duplicate cornTimer multiple times without the timer stopping.  If a player activates all 25 tiles, they will need 25 cornTimer.  I'm wondering if I can add somthing like cornTimer + count:timer = new timer; 
somthing like that.  Any other suggestions?  This part of the game you create a little farm on an isometric map.

```
var menu:menuBG = new menuBG();
var farmSlots:Array = ["empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty"];
var farmSelected = "none";

var cornTimer:Timer = new Timer(100,150);//100 = 10 secs//

farmSlot1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, farmClick1);
farmSlot2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, farmClick2);


cornTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);


function farmClick1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(menu);
    menu.x = 400;
    menu.y = 90;
    menu.buyCornBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyCorn);
    farmSelected = farmSlot1;
}

function buyCorn(e:MouseEvent):void {
    menu.buyCornBtn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cornloading);
    cornTimer.start();
    farmSelected.progressB.visible = true;
    removeChild(menu);
}


function cornloading(e:Event):void {
    var total:Number = 150;
    var loaded:Number = cornTimer.currentCount;
    farmSelected.progressB.bar.scaleX = loaded / total;
    farmSelected.loader_txt.text = Math.round((loaded/total)*100)+ "%";
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    farmSelected.gotoAndStop("corn");
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cornloading);
}


function farmClick2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(menu);
    menu.x = 400;
    menu.y = 90;
    menu.buyCornBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyCorn);
    farmSelected = farmSlot2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ENTER_FRAME event handler on stage, and save the notify functions in an array.So the notify functions will be called in the handler, you don't need to create multi timers.

When a tile becomes active, add a notify on notifies. And the notify function will accept a parameter which indicate the passed time between two frames. You can calculate the passed total time in the tile and do something when the total time equals to the value you want.

Here is a simple class that you can add notify.

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class NotifyUtil {


    private static var _instance:NotifyUtil;

    public static function getInstance():NotifyUtil
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new NotifyUtil();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    public function init(stage:Stage):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private var lastTime:int = 0;

    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        if (lastTime == 0)
        {
            lastTime = getTimer();
            return;
        }

        var now:int = getTimer();

        var passedTime:int = now - lastTime;

        for each (var f:Function in notifies)
        {
            f.apply(null, [passedTime]);
        }

        lastTime = now;
    }

    private var notifies:Array = [];

    public function addNotify(handler:Function):void {

        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (notifies.indexOf(handler) == -1)
        {
            notifies.push(handler);
        }
    }

    public function removeNotify(handler:Function):void
    {
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var index:int = notifies.indexOf(handler);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            notifies.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

}
```